# How do I make a proposal at Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

I have (what I think is) a good proposal idea, but I don't see anywhere to actually propose a Stack Exchange site. What do I need to propose one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I myself see a big link at the bottom of the main page saying "Can't find what you're looking for? [Propose a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create)."

Comment: Do note that this requires 50 reputation, which are easily gained by confirming your email.

Comment: Thanks! maybe it should have a white background or something so it slaps people in the face.